# Differential-equation: Find a solution to $\frac{dy}{dx}=xy+6x+5y+30.$. If necessary, use $k$ to denote an arbitrary constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

How can I go about solving this problem? I do not recognize the type of equation therefore I am not exactly sure what method to use to go about solving it.

> Find a solution to $$\frac{dy}{dx}=xy+6x+5y+30.$$ If necessary, use $k$ to denote an arbitrary constant.

Can someone show me the procedure to solving this differential equation?

Comment: Hint: Note that $xy+6x+5y+30=(x+5)(y+6).$ So this equation is separable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factoring out

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=xy+6x+5y+30$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+5)(y+6) $$

$$\int \frac{dy}{y+6}=\int x+5 dx$$

$$\ln|y+6|=\frac{x^2}{2}+5x+k$$

Answer (score 1):

after the hint above write
$$\frac{dy}{y+6}=(x+5)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to the other answers, which is more algorithmic:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=xy+6x+5y+30=(5+x)y+(6x+30).$$

This is a linear first order differential equation. The general solution is given by the superposition of the homogeneous solution $y_h$ and the particular solution $y_p$.

To determine the homogeneous solution you will have to solve

$$\dfrac{y_h}{dx}=(5+x)y_h$$

which is solvable by separation of variables.

The particular solution can be obtained by the variation of constants ansatz $y_p=c(x)y_h$

$$c'y_h+cy'_h=(5+x)cy_h+(6x+30) \implies c'y_h+c(5+x)y_h=(5+x)cy_h+(6x+30)$$
$$\implies c(x)=\int (6x+30)y_h^{-1}dx.$$

Comment: Although others provided with variable separable solution, this was the first thing I thought after looking at the question!

Comment: I was not clever enough to see the factorization that @ VivekKaushik proposed :D.